# How did a command line Objective-C program create its main NSThread thread?

Tags: objective-c, c, linux, nsthread, gnustep

I am wondering if the a objective-c program itself is a NSThread object. A very simple example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <stdio.h>


int main()
{
  printf("Is this a main thread? %s\n", [NSThread isMainThread] ? "yes" : "no");
  printf("This is the main thread object %p\n", [NSThread mainThread]);

  return(0);
}
```

Run it and it gave:

```
Is this a main thread? yes
This is the main thread object 0x1928430
```

Of course in this program I didn't create my "main thread object" so I am suspecting the objective-c runtime created a NSThread object for me from my main() function. But I do not know how did this magic happen. Would someone educate me what happened between __libc_start_main and my main() function? How does the NSThread class know this is a main thread?

I compiled the code above with:

```
clang  -Werror -g -v -I/usr/local/include -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -fno-objc-arc -lobjc -lgnustep-base mycode.m -o mycode
```

on CentOS linux 6.5.

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/gnustep/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/Reference/NSThread.html: Each process begins with a main thread and additional threads can be created using NSThread.

Comment: Thanks for your pointer, @MartinR. I knew a process begins with a main thread like I illustrated in the example code, but what I really what to know is how was this main NSThread object being created when the program started. I apologize if I didn't make my question clear enough.

Comment: You should find it in the source code: https://github.com/timburks/gnustep-base/blob/master/Source/NSThread.m :) I think the magic is in the `GSCurrentThread()` function.

Comment: Hi @MartinR, thank you very much for your hint and I posted my founding in the answer section. It was a good journey. =)

Answer (score 3):

After more code readings I would like to answer my own question for a future reference. In summery, before calling `[NSThread isMainThread]`, no NSThread was created. Nothing special happened in and before the main() function. The NSThread was created by the side effect of `GSCurrentThread()`.

Code samples based on "gnustep-base-1.24.0". From source file "NSThread.m":

```
+ (BOOL) isMainThread
{
  return (GSCurrentThread() == defaultThread ? YES : NO);
}
```

It calls `GSCurrentThread()` which returns the current NSThread object of this thread.

```
inline NSThread*
GSCurrentThread(void)
{
  NSThread *thr = pthread_getspecific(thread_object_key);
  if (nil == thr)
    {
      GSRegisterCurrentThread();
      thr = pthread_getspecific(thread_object_key);
      if ((nil == defaultThread) && IS_MAIN_PTHREAD)
        {
          defaultThread = [thr retain];
        }
    }
  assert(nil != thr && "No main thread");
  return thr;
}
```

The `thread_object_key` is the static variable of the corresponding thread. It was uninitialized so NSThread object `thr` will be `nil` and it calls `GSRegisterCurrentThread()`.

```
BOOL
GSRegisterCurrentThread (void)
{
  return [NSThread _createThreadForCurrentPthread];
}
```

This function calls the NSThread class method `_createThreadForCurrentPthread`.

```
+ (BOOL) _createThreadForCurrentPthread
{
  NSThread  *t = pthread_getspecific(thread_object_key);

  if (t == nil)
    {
      t = [self new];
      t->_active = YES;
      [[NSGarbageCollector defaultCollector] disableCollectorForPointer: t];
      pthread_setspecific(thread_object_key, t);
      GS_CONSUMED(t);
      return YES;
    }
  return NO;
}
```

Once again the NSThread object `t` will be `nil` and a new NSThead object will be allocated and initialized by the code `t = [self new]`. This NSThread object will be assigned a pthread key, which will be stored in static variable `thread_object_key`.

Finally we returned to the function `GSCurrentThread()`:

```
  if (nil == thr)
    {
      GSRegisterCurrentThread();
      // Returned from here
      thr = pthread_getspecific(thread_object_key);
      if ((nil == defaultThread) && IS_MAIN_PTHREAD)
        {
          defaultThread = [thr retain];
        }
    }
```

`pthread_getspecific()` will be called again but this time the variable `thread_object_key` is associated with a NSThread object from `_createThreadForCurrentPthread`. If `defaultThread` was not set it will be set with our newly created NSThread object, `thr`.

At the end of the stack `[NSThread isMainThread]` will return `YES` since the `defaultThread` is having the NSThread object created by `GSCurrentThread()`. From now on, the process itself can be treated as a NSThread object via the `thread_object_key` which is a static variable of each process/thread. This is how the NSThread object for main function has been created.